# Do I Need a Subquery on SQL View?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I created the first part of the query which shows the total quantity of a product currently waiting to be sent out to customers & returns me the item number from the `Item` table -

```
SELECT
  [Item].[ItemNum],
  SUM([Sales].[Quantity]) AS [Qty]
FROM [dbo].[Item]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Sales]
  ON [Item].[ItemNum] = [Sales].[ItemNum]
WHERE ([Sales].[Sale Type] = 1)
GROUP BY [Item].[ItemNum]
```

That works great, I get the catalogue number of the item and how many are on order.  Now I need to join to another table, which shows me stock of items.  This is what the query looks like -

```
SELECT
  [Item].[ItemNum] SUM ([Sales].[Quantity]) AS [Qty], SUM ([Stock].[Remaining Quantity])
AS [Free Stock]
FROM [dbo].[Item]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Sales]
  ON [Item].[ItemNu]m = [Sales].[ItemNum]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Stock]
  ON [Item].[ItemNum] = [Stock].[ItemNum]
WHERE ([Sales].[Document Type] = 1)
GROUP BY [Item].[ItemNum]
```

Now the quantity on order is way out and the quantity in stock is wrong as well.  As I have the 'where' applied to the sales table but it doesn't apply to the stock table, do I need to move it out?

Thanks

Comment: Without seeing some sample data that generates the issue anything is going to be a guess at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) is useful:

```
With CTE As (
SELECT
  [Item].[ItemNum],
  SUM([Sales].[Quantity]) AS [Qty]
FROM [dbo].[Item]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Sales]
  ON [Item].[ItemNum] = [Sales].[ItemNum]
WHERE ([Sales].[Sale Type] = 1)
GROUP BY [Item].[ItemNum]
 )
  Select *
    From CTE Left Outer Join
     [dbo].[Stock]
  ON [CTE].[ItemNum] = [Stock].[ItemNum]
```

Comment: Yes, I am a little closer now!  My stock quantity is now correct, but the sales quantity (from CTE) is still incorrect.  Trying to figure out why that might be.

Comment: I ended up using multiple CTE's - thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will fix your problem but the where clause is turning your left join into an inner join. Try this instead.

```
SELECT
  dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum, SUM (dbo.[databasename$Sales].Quantity) AS [Qty], SUM (dbo.[databasename$Stock.[Remaining Quantity])
AS [Free Stock]
FROM dbo.[databasename$Item]
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[databasename$Sales]
  ON dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum = dbo.[databasename$Sales].ItemNum
  AND (dbo.[databasename$Sales].[Document Type] = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[databasename$Stock]
  ON dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum = dbo.[databasename$Stock].[ItemNum]
GROUP BY dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum
```

Try this  and see if it fixes the issue:

```
SELECT
  dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum, [databasename$Sales].Quantity) AS [Qty], [databasename$Stock.[Remaining Quantity])
AS [Free Stock]
FROM dbo.[databasename$Item]
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ItemNum, sum(quantity) as Quantity from dbo.[databasename$Sales] where Document Type = 1group by ItemNum) as databasename$Sales
  ON dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum = [databasename$Sales].ItemNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select ItemNum, sum(quantity)  as RemainingQuantity from dbo.[databasename$Stock]roup by ItemNum)
as databasename$Stock
  ON dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum = [databasename$Stock].[ItemNum]
GROUP BY dbo.[databasename$Item].ItemNum
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: But it will keep you from filtering out records you didn't want to filter out. You should read this:http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Comment: Sorry, should have said it didn't fix the original problem, but I see now how it will help with the query in general.

Comment: Likely your issue is indeed that the sums need to be done in derived tables. If you have joined to this table with 12 records and this other table with 15 records then the sums will be off .